# How to directly set a JSON array in VBA(without iterating), that is retrieved from webapp in google sheet's range?

Tags: excel, vba, google-apps-script, web-applications

How do I change the code so that i can retrieve data in an array in google sheet range with criteria; if the first column date value is not the same then the all data is overwritten but if it is the same then it is not.

```js
function getJsonData(){
  
 var spreadSheetId='YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID';
  
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadSheetId);
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Validation_sheet");
  
  var json_data = getData(sheet);
return json_data;

function getData(sheet){
  
  var jo = {};
  var i =0;
  var rows2 = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
   Logger.clear();
//  ===============Get data=================
  var rows2=[];
  var rangeData = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = rangeData.getValues();
  var lastColumn = rangeData.getLastColumn();
  var lastRow = rangeData.getLastRow();
// Logger.log("lastrow=>"+ lastRow);
  var data=[];
  var x=0,y=0;
  for(i = 0; i<lastRow; i++){
    data[x]=[];
    
    for(var j=0; j<lastColumn; j++ ){ 
    
      if(email == values[i][2]){
        
        data[x][j]= values[i][j];
        y=1;
      }
    }
    if(y==1){ x=x+1; y=0; }
 
  }
  return data;  
}
```

and I also include the vba code to retrieve data from google sheet via webapp,

```vb
Sub Retrieve()
  Dim myurl As String 'for store URL from google
  Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0") 'To use POST http Request
  Data = "{""dataReq"":[], " & vbNewLine & "  ""fname"":""getData""}"

  'Define the google URL
  myurl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyQbRuYXTvVheZQIC6Gmaj0DMkbMnBVh8JLQS_q8QUPOMIB_t0/exec"
  xmlhttp.Open "POST", myurl, False
  xmlhttp.send Data
  sGetResult = xmlhttp.ResponseText
  Set JsonObject = JsonConverter.ParseJson(sGetResult)

  Row = 0
  For Each dataRow In JsonObject
      Row = Row + 1
      Column = 0
      For Each dataCell In dataRow
          Column = Column + 1
          Cells(Row, Column) = dataCell
      Next
  Next
  
End Sub
```

but the above vba code can only retrieve values ​​row by row, how can it be done directly through arrays instead of row by row, How to Use Arrays Instead of Ranges ?

Comment: What do you mean by _directly_ and _copy_?

Comment: How to Use Arrays Instead of Ranges

Comment: [Edit] your last comment into the question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you are trying to accomplish something like this but I don't understand what the criteria is and I can't really follow most of your code.

```
function getJsonData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadSheetId");
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Validation_sheet");
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues().filter(r => r[0] == "some criteria").filter(r => r != 'undefined');
  return JSON.stringify(vs);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry my English makes you confused, I can't speak well, the criteria are the date in the source column with the date in the target column, if the contents of the column are the same as the target column then it is not copied otherwise if it is not the same then overwrite